# Django gives error even though database is connected

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, djongo

i dont know why. but it works well on local pc
and i putted it on CPanel
its connected to database. but when i load a page. it gives dbError:

this code works in localhost ( on my pc )
but when i uploaded it on cpanel it gives error ;/ ( db is on cpanel )

DBCode: The DBName and username and password is currect

```py
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': '(db names are currect)',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
            'CLIENT': {
                'host': 'mongodb://(entered username):(entered password)@localhost:27017/( iwrote db name)'
                    }  
                }
            }
```

i got putted __in and [ ] cuz i heared that djongo needs booleans to be like this
And Views.Py

```py
stores = Store.objects.filter(Premium__in=[True])
    
return render(request, 'base/home.html', context={'stores': stores})
```

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://www.storefa.xyz/home/

Django Version: 4.0.6
Python Version: 3.9.12
Installed Applications:
['captcha',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'base.apps.BaseConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/storefax/StoreFa/base/templates/base/home.html, error at line 72
   (Could not get exception message)
   62 :     </div>
   63 :     <br>
   64 :     <br>
   65 :     <br>
   66 :     <br>
   67 :     <div class="about-container">
   68 :         <div class="kh kh-1"></div>
   69 :         <div class="kh kh-2"></div>
   70 :         <div class="kh kh-3"></div>
   71 : 
   72 :          {% for store in stores %} 
   73 :         <div class="about-column">
   74 :             <div class="img-name">
   75 :                 <br>
   76 :                 <img width="100px" height="100px" src="{{store.icon}}">
   77 :                 <div class="go-up">
   78 :                     <p class="icon-fa">{% if store.Premium %}<i class="fa fa-star"></i> {% endif %}{{store.name}}</p>
   79 :                     <br>
   80 :                     <h4>یکی از بهترین فروشگاه های</h4>
   81 :                     <h4>ایران برای گیم</h4>
   82 :                     <br>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 808, in __iter__
    yield from iter(self._query)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 166, in __iter__
    for doc in cursor:
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1248, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1165, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1052, in __send_message
    response = client._run_operation(
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1267, in _run_operation
    return self._retryable_read(
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1364, in _retryable_read
    server = self._select_server(read_pref, session, address=address)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1186, in _select_server
    topology = self._get_topology()
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1143, in _get_topology
    self._topology.open()
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 188, in open
    self._ensure_opened()
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 573, in _ensure_opened
    raise InvalidOperation("Cannot use MongoClient after close")

The above exception (Cannot use MongoClient after close) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 65, in fetchmany
    ret.append(self.result.next())
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 797, in __next__
    result = next(self._result_generator)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 830, in __iter__
    raise exe from e

The above exception (

    Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT "base_store"."id", "base_store"."host_id", "base_store"."guild_id", "base_store"."name", "base_store"."Invite", "base_store"."description", "base_store"."Premium", "base_store"."Partner", "base_store"."icon", "base_store"."membercount" FROM "base_store" WHERE "base_store"."Premium" IN (%(0)s)
Params: (True,)
Version: 1.3.6
    Sub SQL: None
    FAILED SQL: None
    Params: None
    Version: None) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 70, in fetchmany
    raise db_exe from e

The above exception () was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/storefax/StoreFa/base/views.py", line 61, in home
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context={'stores': stores})
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 62, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 194, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 302, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1394, in execute_sql
    return list(result)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1873, in cursor_iter
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1873, in <lambda>
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/storefax/virtualenv/StoreFa/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 70, in fetchmany
    raise db_exe from e

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /home/
Exception Value:
```

Comment: Well `__in` and lists go together but not if you just want to check a boolean, what's wrong with `.filter(premium=True)`?

Comment: idk its boolean problem of djongo

Comment: What version of djongo and pymongo are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely has to do something with your database connection as the most important part of the error's traceback is:

```
    Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT "base_store"."id", "base_store"."host_id", "base_store"."guild_id", "base_store"."name", "base_store"."Invite", "base_store"."description", "base_store"."Premium", "base_store"."Partner", "base_store"."icon", "base_store"."membercount" FROM "base_store" WHERE "base_store"."Premium" IN (%(0)s)
```

Thus, I would highly recommend you to test out the MongoDB URI connection that you use and make sure it's properly accessing the necessary database.